# case insensitive search in angular js

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, html

I have below code for filter list in angular js, with the pagination of 10 records per page.It gives the proper result but the result is case sensitive. I want it case insensitive. I have tried some solution from SO but the didn't work so I'm posting tis question.

HTML code:

```
 <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search for members in first name,last name and email" ng-model="query"  class="form-control input-box">

    <tr ng-repeat="item in filterData = (totalItems| filter : search) | limitTo:10:10*(page-1)" ng-cloak> </tr>
```

JS Code:

```
$scope.search = function (row) {

    return !!(( row.member_fname.indexOf($scope.query || '') !== - 1  || row.member_lname.indexOf($scope.query || '') !== - 1 || row.member_email.indexOf($scope.query || '') !== - 1));
    };
```

Comment: post only relevant code, reformat using proper indentation, attach an example of your data (`totalItems`?)

Answer (score 0):

Add toLowerCase() or toUpperCase() to all of the string references.

```
$scope.search = function (row) {

    return !!(( row.member_fname.toLowerCaseindexOf($scope.query.toLowerCase() || '') !== - 1  || row.member_lname.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.query.toLowerCase() || '') !== - 1 || row.member_email.toLowerCase()indexOf($scope.query.toLowerCase() || '') !== - 1));
};
```

Comment: You may also need to trim $scope.query. There might be an issue with leading/trailing spaces. I'd eliminate the double negation at the beginning of the expression as well.

Comment: ok it works only for lowercase letters.. but when I'm trying with capital letter it is not showing me any results.

Comment: You've got something else going on. I'd recommend revising the question with more details.